# How do i fix discord client command not working in Python

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a bot in Discord written in The Python programming language.  Ive watched a few tutorials cause i couldn't get it to work by myself and i noticed all the people used the Client = discord.Client() 
command after importing needed files for running the program.  When i try to run the app, it says

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testbot.py", line 2, in <module>
import discord.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.client'
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please reply and let me know!
Thanks!

Here's my code for the bot!

```
import discord

Client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == '/testconnection':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Connection     successfully established with Discord NET")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('-------')




client.run("my discord bot token goes here but i'm hiding it ")
```

Answer (score 2):

`import discord.client` This line does not appear anywhere in the code you posted.

You're assigning `discord.Client()` to `Client`, but using `client` in the rest of your code.  Names are case-sensitive, so you should change that line to

```
client = discord.Client()
```

Comment: I've fixed the capitalization errors, but when i try to import discord.client i get this

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testbot.py", line 2, in <module>
         import discord.Client
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.Client'

Comment: Just `import discord` and then use `discord.Client` to refer to that class in your code.

Comment: it says there is no attribute named Client